# RequiredIf Conditional Validation Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validationattribute

I was looking for some advice on the best way to go about implementing a validation attribute that does the following.

Model

```
public class MyInputModel 
{
    [Required]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string MyProperty1 {get;set;}
    public string MyProperty2 {get;set;}
    public bool MyProperty3 {get;set;}

}
```

I want to have atleast prop1 prop2 prop3 with a value and if prop3 is the only value filled it it should not equal false.
How would i go about writing a validation attribute(s?) for this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may checkout the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) for a sample implementation of a `[RequiredIf]` custom validation attribute. It compares against a single other property value but you could easily tweak the `IsValid` method to meet your requirements.

Comment: just a small not on the `ExpressiveAnnotations`. The package is not supported above .NET 4.8

Comment: there is a fork of ExpressiveAnnotations for .NET Core (also on NuGet)

Answer (score 122):

I had the same problem yesterday, but I did it in a very clean way which works for both client side and server side validation.

**Condition**: Based on the value of other property in the model, you want to make another property required. Here is the code:

```cs
public class RequiredIfAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
  private String PropertyName { get; set; }
  private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }

  public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
  {
    PropertyName = propertyName;
    DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
  }

  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
  {
    Object instance = context.ObjectInstance;
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    Object proprtyvalue = type.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null);
    if (proprtyvalue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
    {
      ValidationResult result = base.IsValid(value, context);
      return result;
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

**`PropertyName`** is the property on which you want to make your condition
**`DesiredValue`** is the particular value of the PropertyName (property) for which your other property has to be validated for required

Say you have the following:

```
public enum UserType
{
  Admin,
  Regular
}

public class User
{
  public UserType UserType {get;set;}

  [RequiredIf("UserType",UserType.Admin,
              ErrorMessageResourceName="PasswordRequired", 
              ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceString))]
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

At last but not the least, register adapter for your attribute so that it can do client side validation  (I put it in global.asax, Application_Start)

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredIfAttribute),
                                                      typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

EDITED

Some people have reported issues that the client side fires no matter what or it does not work. So I modified the above code to do conditional client side validation with Javascript as well. For this case you don't need to register adapter

```
 public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private String PropertyName { get; set; }
        private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
        private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
            _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var dependentValue = context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
                ValidationType = "requiredif",
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = (context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName);
            rule.ValidationParameters["desiredvalue"] = DesiredValue is bool ? DesiredValue.ToString().ToLower() : DesiredValue;

            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

And finally the javascript ( bundle it and renderit...put it in its own script file)

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredif', ['dependentproperty', 'desiredvalue'], function (options) {
    options.rules['requiredif'] = options.params;
    options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
});

$.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, parameters) {
    var desiredvalue = parameters.desiredvalue;
    desiredvalue = (desiredvalue == null ? '' : desiredvalue).toString();
    var controlType = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']").attr("type");
    var actualvalue = {}
    if (controlType == "checkbox" || controlType == "radio") {
        var control = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']:checked");
        actualvalue = control.val();
    } else {
        actualvalue = $("#" + parameters.dependentproperty).val();
    }
    if ($.trim(desiredvalue).toLowerCase() === $.trim(actualvalue).toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        var isValid = $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
        return isValid;
    }
    return true;
});
```

You need obviously the unobstrusive validate jQuery to be included as requirement

Comment: @Dan Hunex : In MVC4 I have not managed to work properly on client side and it fires up the validation no matter what the DesiredValue is. Any help pls?

Comment: Can I see the attribute you created

Comment: Same issue as @H.Johnson. The client side validation fires no matter what. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: I am having the same issue.  It fires no matter what.

Comment: For those of you who find it not working client side, I have added a newer version with javascript

Comment: Interesting I did the edit withowt being logged in .. hmmm ..but ok I hope this will help some when searching for this same thing.

Comment: Fantastic reply here, +1 from me, but could you explain the following

`ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ResourceStrings))`

ResourceStrings is not recognised on my VS2013.

Comment: Ignore this, I've fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: works great. you can avoid including the above validate script and reuse the already available "Required" client-side validation by setting `ErrorMessage = string.Format("{0} is required.", metadata.DisplayName), validationType = "required"` in RequiredIfAttribute.cs

Comment: @cronixis Thats Worked! Thanks

Comment: how do I force radio button if textbox not empty [RequiredIf("SomeTextBox", "what to say here" , ErrorMessage = "Message")]

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you are concerned about Localization and need the standard RequiredAttribute validation messages, you can just simply set ErrorMessage = _innerAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()) in the GetClientValidationRules

Comment: So for me, this kept returning "This field is required" in the summary and I couldn't get the correct message to show. I think there is a mismatch by calling the existing `required` method, but setting the message on the new `requiredif` method. What I did was swap out the 2 lines inside the comparison if check (the one with the `$.trim` statements) and replaced it with the code inside the `required` method inside jquery.validate.js. Basically do the same thing the `required` method does, but inside the `requiredif` method so the correct message shows.

Comment: @DanHunex Could you please explain how to use the JS code you wrote? Could you give an example of where exactly to write it and how will it be used?

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky As I stated , put it in its own file, bundle it and it will work automatically when you use the RequiredIf attribute in your model classes. How to bundle?! you may take a look at this http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/scriptbundle-mvc

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for saving me hours of working out the code itself

Comment: @MikeUpjohn Could you tell me how did you fix `ErrorMessageResourceType` problem? Mine not working.

Comment: I had to add `|| "false"` to make RequiredIf(checkbox) work:
    `if (controlType == "checkbox" || controlType == "radio") {
            var control = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']:checked");
            actualvalue = control.val() || "false";`

Comment: @devio Yes. You can do that. I wrote this based on checkbox. If you even have other control type to depend, you can add more conditions

Comment: The type System.Web.Mvc.RequiredAttributeAdapter must have a public constructor which accepts three parameters of types System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, and RequiredIfAttribute
Parameter name: adapterType

Comment: Correct. But how can I deal with the custom property with condition.I am not getting `PropertyName` from the context into the `[dependentproperty]`.. Thats OK. I've change the code and directly assisgn `PropertyName` into `[dependentproperty]` but then in jquery the filed with the same name not available in html context. So actula value is still undefined,

Comment: @DanHunex I have to implement this type of validation in ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1. Do you have any idea, how to implement?

Comment: @Simant You should use a similar approach. The documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0 gives good example of custom validation

Answer (score 35):

I know the topic was asked some time ago, but recently I had faced similar issue and found yet another, but in my opinion a more complete solution. I decided to implement mechanism which provides conditional attributes to calculate validation results based on other properties values and relations between them, which are defined in logical expressions.

Using it you are able to achieve the result you asked about in the following manner:

```
[RequiredIf("MyProperty2 == null && MyProperty3 == false")]
public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("MyProperty1 == null && MyProperty3 == false")]
public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }

[AssertThat("MyProperty1 != null || MyProperty2 != null || MyProperty3 == true")]
public bool MyProperty3 { get; set; }
```

More information about ExpressiveAnnotations library [**can be found here**](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations). It should simplify many declarative validation cases without the necessity of writing additional case-specific attributes or using imperative way of validation inside controllers.

Comment: Many, many thanks for this library.  In terms of extensibility, it beats all the others.

Comment: I applied all the steps mentioned on https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations but did not worked for me giving the following error: "The type System.Web.Mvc.RequiredAttributeAdapter must have a public constructor which accepts three parameters of types System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, and ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes.RequiredIfAttribute
Parameter name: adapterType"

Comment: @H.Johnson: This exception is unlikely to occur. I assume there is an issue in your code (maybe you have types ambiguity - are you sure that in your Global.asax you have registered adapters for attributes from appropriate namespace i.e. ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes, and not any other ones?). To help you I need more information, above is to less. Finally take a look at [sample project](https://github.com/JaroslawWaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations/tree/master/src/ExpressiveAnnotations.MvcWebSample) on github and try to investigate where is the difference.

Comment: @H.Johnson: ad 1) MvcUnobtrusiveValidatorProvider.dll should be added automatically to your references by NuGet. If for some reason it is not there - add reference manually. ad 2) For client-side validation to work, despite ExpressiveAnnotations.dll, mentioned MvcUnobtrusiveValidatorProvider.dll also needs to be there. What's more the expressive.annotations.validate.js should be included in bundle below jquery validation files, and added on specified page (see sample proj).

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko: Thanks for your kind help. Actually your message encouraged me and I tried again. I do not know what the problem was, but by the last try I have managed to work it "on server and client side". That is exactly wonderful & simple and most flexible I have searched for many web sites. Thanks a lot for your nice example and help. I voted up ;)

Comment: On the other hand, for my prior message I had managed to find ExpressiveAnnotations.MvcUnobtrusiveValidatorProvider.dll from the project I tried first. Thanks a lot again for your consideration.

Comment: Just a head's-up, this requires bootstrap 3.0.1.1 or higher. I can't use it because we're using Bootstrap 3.0.0.

Comment: Thank you so much for this... we should all up vote this. This solves those complex "required if" validations :)

Comment: Is this library only for ASP.NET, and not ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 14):

## I got it to work on ASP.NET **MVC 5**

I saw many people interested in and suffering from this code and i know it's really confusing and disrupting for the first time.

## Notes

- worked on MVC 5 on both server and client side :D
- I didn't install "ExpressiveAnnotations" library at all.
- I'm taking about the Original code from "**@Dan Hunex**", Find him above

## **Tips To Fix This Error**

> "The type System.Web.Mvc.RequiredAttributeAdapter must have a public constructor which accepts three parameters of types System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, and ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes.RequiredIfAttribute Parameter name: adapterType"

**Tip #1:** make sure that you're inheriting from '**ValidationAttribute**' not from '**RequiredAttribute**'

```
 public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable { ...}
```

**Tip #2:** OR remove this entire line from '**Global.asax**', It is not needed at all in the newer version of the code (after edit by @Dan_Hunex),  and yes this line was a must in the old version ...

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredIfAttribute), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

## **Tips To Get The Javascript Code Part Work**

1- put the code in a new js file (ex:requiredIfValidator.js)

2- warp the code inside a $(document).ready(function(){........});

3- include our js file after including the JQuery validation libraries, So it look like this now :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Content/JS/requiredIfValidator.js"></script>
```

4- Edit the C# code

from

```
rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = (context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName);
```

to

```
rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = PropertyName;
```

and from

```
if (dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
```

to

```
if (dependentValue != null && dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
```

## **My Entire Code Up and Running**

**Global.asax**

Nothing to add here, keep it clean

**requiredIfValidator.js**

create this file in ~/content or in ~/scripts folder

```
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('requiredif', ['dependentproperty', 'desiredvalue'], function (options)
{
    options.rules['requiredif'] = options.params;
    options.messages['requiredif'] = options.message;
});


$(document).ready(function ()
{

    $.validator.addMethod('requiredif', function (value, element, parameters) {
        var desiredvalue = parameters.desiredvalue;
        desiredvalue = (desiredvalue == null ? '' : desiredvalue).toString();
        var controlType = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']").attr("type");
        var actualvalue = {}
        if (controlType == "checkbox" || controlType == "radio") {
            var control = $("input[id$='" + parameters.dependentproperty + "']:checked");
            actualvalue = control.val();
        } else {
            actualvalue = $("#" + parameters.dependentproperty).val();
        }
        if ($.trim(desiredvalue).toLowerCase() === $.trim(actualvalue).toLocaleLowerCase()) {
            var isValid = $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
            return isValid;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

**_Layout.cshtml or the View**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="~/Content/JS/requiredIfValidator.js"></script>
```

**RequiredIfAttribute.cs Class**

create it some where in your project, For example in ~/models/customValidation/

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Your_Project_Name.Models.CustomValidation
{
    public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
    {
        private String PropertyName { get; set; }
        private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
        private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

        public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
        {
            PropertyName = propertyName;
            DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
            _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
        {
            var dependentValue = context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (dependentValue != null && dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
            {
                if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });
                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
                ValidationType = "requiredif",
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = PropertyName;
            rule.ValidationParameters["desiredvalue"] = DesiredValue is bool ? DesiredValue.ToString().ToLower() : DesiredValue;

            yield return rule;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Model**

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Your_Project_Name.Models.CustomValidation;

namespace Your_Project_Name.Models.ViewModels
{

    public class CreateOpenActivity
    {
        public Nullable<int> ORG_BY_CD { get; set; }

        [RequiredIf("ORG_BY_CD", "5", ErrorMessage = "Coordinator ID is required")] // This means: IF 'ORG_BY_CD' is equal 5 (for the example)  > make 'COR_CI_ID_NUM' required and apply its all validation / data annotations
        [RegularExpression("[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Enter Numbers Only")]
        [MaxLength(9, ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid ID Number")]
        [MinLength(9, ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid ID Number")]
        public string COR_CI_ID_NUM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The View**

Nothing to note here actually ...

```
    @model Your_Project_Name.Models.ViewModels.CreateOpenActivity
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Testing";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CreateOpenActivity</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORG_BY_CD, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORG_BY_CD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORG_BY_CD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.COR_CI_ID_NUM, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.COR_CI_ID_NUM, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.COR_CI_ID_NUM, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**I may upload a project sample for this later ...**

**Hope this was helpful**

**Thank You**

Comment: I had a problem with the client error messages coming back as "The field [object Object] is invalid."  If you encounter the same, replace `ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,` with `ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage ?? string.Format(ErrorMessageString, metadata.DisplayName),`

Comment: @Adel Mourad I have to implement a similar kind of validation in ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1. Do you have any idea how to implement this code in asp.net MVC Core?

Comment: @Simant You many switch the required validation on/off manually using C# and JS. For C# use the ModelState.Remove(PropName") to remove the validation from some property before calling ModelState.IsValid ....

Comment: @AdelMourad thank you for this complete solution. I just have a remark or improvement : it will be better to replace dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString() by string.Equals(dependentValue.ToString(), DesiredValue.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or add string comparaison mode as parameter

Answer (score 2):

If you try to use "ModelState.Remove" or "ModelState["Prop"].Errors.Clear()" the "ModelState.IsValid" stil returns false.

Why not just removing the default "Required" Annotation from Model and make your custom validation before the "ModelState.IsValid" on Controller 'Post' action? Like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourClass.Property1) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(yourClass.dependantProperty))            
            ModelState.AddModelError("dependantProperty", "It´s necessary to select some 'dependant'.");
```

Comment: I found this solution the easiest. The error raised this way even shows together with errors raised by the built in `[Required]` attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the notes from Adel Mourad and Dan Hunex, I amended the code to provide an example that only accepts values that **do not** match the given value.

I also found that I didn't need the JavaScript.

I added the following class to my Models folder:

```
public class RequiredIfNotAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object InvalidValue { get; set; }
    private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;

    public RequiredIfNotAttribute(String propertyName, Object invalidValue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        InvalidValue = invalidValue;
        _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        var dependentValue = context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (dependentValue.ToString() != InvalidValue.ToString())
        {
            if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(context.DisplayName), new[] { context.MemberName });
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "requiredifnot",
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["dependentproperty"] = (context as ViewContext).ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(PropertyName);
        rule.ValidationParameters["invalidvalue"] = InvalidValue is bool ? InvalidValue.ToString().ToLower() : InvalidValue;

        yield return rule;
    }
```

I didn't need to make any changes to my view, but did make a change to the properties of my model:

```
    [RequiredIfNot("Id", 0, ErrorMessage = "Please select a Source")]
    public string TemplateGTSource { get; set; }

    public string TemplateGTMedium
    {
        get
        {
            return "Email";
        }
    }

    [RequiredIfNot("Id", 0, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Campaign")]
    public string TemplateGTCampaign { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfNot("Id", 0, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Term")]
    public string TemplateGTTerm { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The main difference from other solutions here is that this one reuses logic in `RequiredAttribute` on the server side, and uses `required`'s validation method `depends` property on the client side:

```
public class RequiredIf : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }
    public object OtherPropertyValue { get; private set; }

    public RequiredIf(string otherProperty, object otherPropertyValue)
    {
        OtherProperty = otherProperty;
        OtherPropertyValue = otherPropertyValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyInfo otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);
        if (otherPropertyInfo == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"Unknown property {OtherProperty}");
        }

        object otherValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
        if (Equals(OtherPropertyValue, otherValue)) // if other property has the configured value
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationType = "requiredif"; // data-val-requiredif
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("other", OtherProperty); // data-val-requiredif-other
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherval", OtherPropertyValue); // data-val-requiredif-otherval

        yield return rule;
    }
}

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("requiredif", ["other", "otherval"], function (options) {
    var value = {
        depends: function () {
            var element = $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + options.params.other + "']")[0];
            return element && $(element).val() == options.params.otherval;
        }
    }
    options.rules["required"] = value;
    options.messages["required"] = options.message;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [IValidatableObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ivalidatableobject) is a good choice.

```
public class MyInputModel : IValidateObject
{
    [Required]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string MyProperty1 {get;set;}
    public string MyProperty2 {get;set;}
    public bool MyProperty3 {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (MyProperty1==null&&MyProperty2==null&&MyPropterty3!=false) //whatever condition
        {
        yield return new ValidationResult(
            "Custom complex error");
        }
    }

}
```