# Validate experience dropdown with jQuery with minimum and maximum values

Tags: jquery, html, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

**I am using mvc4**

I have 2 dropdownlist one is `minimum experience` and the oher is `maximum experience`, i am trying to validate minimum with maximum vice-versa from client side, but not getting it worked in a way i want it. The things i want to achieve like..

**1**. *Minimum should be always less than maximum.*

**2**. *if minimum and maximum both are `0` then it should go on.*

**3**. *both can allow blank (Don't want to give min value or max value), i mean that user can also select default values as it is like `---minimum---` and `---maximum---`.*

**4**. *if minimum is not selected just maximum is selected then it should go on. same case in minimum too.*

So far i have this:

Created [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLkX6/2/) to illustrate idea.

**jQuery**

**_ **_EDITED** *_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

**Reached so close, Come up to this, now just one thing remaning, `maximum` is checked as a value and compared, but i want to ignore it via condition.**

```
$("#MinExperienceDropDown").change(function () {
     if ((($(this).val()) != "" && ($("#MaxExperienceDropDown").val() != "")) && ($("#MaxExperienceDropDown").val() != "") && ($(this).val() > $("#MaxExperienceDropDown").val())) {
                 alert('Minimum expreience should be less than maximum');
            }
        });
 $("#MaxExperienceDropDown").change(function () {
           if ($(this).val() < $("#MinExperienceDropDown").val()) {
              alert('Maximum expreience should be greater than minimum');
           }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align: left">
   <select name="MinExperience" id="MinExperienceDropDown" style="width: 32%" class="select">
      <option value="">--Minimum--</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
   <select name="MaxExperience" id="MaxExperienceDropDown" style="width: 32%; float: right;margin-right: 82px" class="select">
      <option value="">--Maximum--</option>
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Thank you all** in advance.

Comment: I assume you're looking for client side validation? This question should get you started on server-side: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13764684/534109 - in a nutshell, nothing is baked into MVC at the moment to get you unobtrusive validation.

Comment: _I edited my question, so close to the goal._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this closer to what you want?  If not, it should at least be easier to edit from this point forward I hope.

**JS**

```
//Cache these as variables so we only have to select once
var $min= $("#MinExperienceDropDown");
var $max = $("#MaxExperienceDropDown");
var $msg = $("#message");

//Apply a single change event to fire on either dropdown
$min.add($max).change(function () {
    //Have some default text to display, an empty string
    var text = "";
        
    //Cache the vales as variables so we don't have to keep getting them
    //We will parse the numbers out of the string values
    var minVal = parseInt($min.val(),10);
    var maxVal = parseInt($max.val(),10)
    
    //Determine if both are numbers, if so then they both have values
    var bothHaveValues = !isNaN(minVal) && !isNaN(maxVal);
    
    if(bothHaveValues){
        if(minVal > maxVal){
            text += 'Minimum expreience should be less than maximum';
        }else if(maxVal < minVal){
            text += 'Maximum expreience should be greater than minimum';
        }
    }
    
    //Display the text
    $msg.html(text);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="MaxExperienceDropDown">Min Experience</label>
<select name="MinExperience" id="MinExperienceDropDown">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>
    
<label for="MaxExperienceDropDown">Max Experience</label>
<select name="MaxExperience" id="MaxExperienceDropDown">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<div id="message"></div>
```

---

## DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pLkX6/3/

Comment: Wow Chris... It worked like a charm. this is exactly what i wanted. +1

Comment: Can we hide the value which unnecessary for user instead of  showing "Minimum expreience should be less than maximum" the message ? if yes please tell me

Comment: Let If user select 50 lacs in minimum value then maximum option value automaticly hide below 50 lacs value then user cant see below 50 lacs

Answer (score 1):

Write one javascript method

```
function validation(){
if($("#MaxExperienceDropDown").val() != "" && $("#MinExperienceDropDown").val() != "" &&  (($("#MaxExperienceDropDown").val() != 0 && $("#MinExperienceDropDown").val() != 0) || ($("#MaxExperienceDropDown").val() < $("#MinExperienceDropDown").val()))){
 //your alert message here
}
}
```

call this method from onChange event of both the dropdown as given below

```
$("#MinExperienceDropDown").change(function () {
    validation()
        });
 $("#MaxExperienceDropDown").change(function () {
          validation()
  });
```