# Perform conditional validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to conditionally validate a field with the server side validation helpers?

E.G.

```
public partial class SomeEntity
{
   public bool Chargeable { get; set; }
   [RegularExpression(@"\d{8,8}", ErrorMessage = "should have alpha numeric characters.")]
   public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**Requirement:** CaseNumber is required if and only if Chargeable is true.

I could do:

```
 [RegularExpression(@"\d{8,8}", ErrorMessage = "should have alpha numeric characters."), Required]
 public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
```

However, `Required(if(Chargeable))` is what I need...

Comment: possible duplicate of [RequiredIf Conditional Validation Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your SomeEntity class implement the **IValidatableObject** interface.