# Validation based on Conditions ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-validation

Am not sure if am  repeating question but i didn't get exact answer for what am looking for

Am having strongly typed view which i bind from model

```
//Model

[Required]
public string sample { get; set; }

public bool isAllowed { get; set; }
```

Am allowing the only particular group of users to edit the sample based on the isAllowed Property

```
//View
if (Model.isAllowed)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sample)
}
```

So now required field works if user is allowed but in other part validation fires there comes my problem.

How do i handle this  and disable the required field for the other set of users ?

Or Does MVC have any standard in creating  my view for this scenarios ?

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding the question correctly, you can render it as a hidden property if isAllowed is false, so your code should be something like this

```
if (Model.isAllowed)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sample)
}
else
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.sample)
}
```

Comment: what if sample is empty ? i ll get required field validation no ?

Comment: You can assign a default value in this case @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.sample,new{value ="default value "})... Another way however strongly discouraged is to manually remove the error from the Modelstate object in your controller if Isallowed is false so it passes the IsValid check

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for RequiredIf validation attribute. You can start here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx

And then if you want client side validation for it too you can look at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/11/adding-client-side-script-to-an-mvc-conditional-validator.aspx

Similar question was asked here:

[RequiredIf Conditional Validation Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute)