# Remove object from modelstate validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two models:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //...

    public bool Falg{ get; set; }
}

public class UserInfoExtra
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

Those two models are combined in a ViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    public UserInfoExtra ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel userinfo)
{
    if(userInfo.Flag){
        //Remove ExtaInfo from validation in ModelState.IsValid?
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserInfos.Add(userinfo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(userinfo);
}
```

How can I remove the `ExtraInfo` from validation in `ModelState.IsValid`?

Comment: You can use `ModelState[key].Errors.Clear();` to remove individual errors

Comment: You can go with  Stephen's comment or if you have client validation enabled then do force submit(form) with jquery and on server side just do ModelState[key].Errors.Clear(); or if(ModelState.IsValidField(UserInfo)){//model state for userinfor is valid
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing errors from `ModelState` is not a good idea. If you don't want the `UserInfoExtra` class to be validated when using the `UserViewModel`, then you should define your View Model differently (like below), and then use conditional validation on the PhoneNumber property:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    //[RequiredIf] (conditional validation here)...
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set;}
}
```

Here you can find an implementation of `RequiredIf` attribute: [RequiredIf Conditional Validation Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

1. Ignore other properties(other than UserInfo) : **ModelState.IsValidField(UserInfo)**
2. Clear/Remove property error : **ModelState["ExtraInfo"].Errors.Clear();**
3. Create custom validator, as also suggested by **ataravati** : [MVC Custom validation attribute](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method that you can write to group all the modelstate errors as a Dictionary collection and now you can remove an item using it's key.

```
public static IEnumerable Errors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    if (!modelState.IsValid)
    {
        return modelState.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
            kvp => kvp.Value.Errors
                            .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray())
                            .Where(m => m.Value.Count() > 0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and you can access the modelstate error collection by `var errors = ModelState.Errors();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="ExtraInfo")]UserViewModel userinfo)
{
...
}
```

Hope will help.

Comment: This will exclude `ExtraInfo` from binding, not only validation.

Comment: hmm. yes i missed that.. 
then only option is to override OnModelCreating method i think.