# RequiredIf not working in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, client-side-validation

I would like to know if there exists `RequiredIf` annotation in MVC 5 because I'm in trouble trying to use it because it seems that it doesn't exists in MVC 5. Is there any solution, or I'm missing some library? (I know it exists in MVC3).

Also is there any alternative for conditional validation in MVC 5?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried implement your attribute? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute

Comment: Whoever downvoted explain please..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Required if` is not a built-in attribute. You need to download and import third party library:

[**MVC Foolproof Validation**](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I did as you mentioned above but still not working .Using it in the following way
[RequiredIf("GSMEthernetMAC", "", ErrorMessageResourceType = "Please enter WiFiMac")]
        public string WifiMAC { get; set; }
If GSMEthernetMAC is empty then only it will throw a message.

Comment: @vivek did you import the dll, which error do you see

Comment: dll is imported.I forgot to add the js files ..
After adding 3 js files (1 - mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min 2 - MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min. 3 - MvcFoolproofValidation.min)i am getting the below error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined(anonymous function) @ mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js:

Comment: You should not have to import anything else but the dll, If you have trouble use the nugget package manager , see here https://www.nuget.org/packages/foolproof  `Install-Package foolproof`

Comment: I can able to make it work . Actually i forgot to add the dependent js files for foolproof plugins . I am facing one more issue that is when i am navigating to that page from another page its not working but when i hit ctrl+f5 for the same page , it works like a charm. Can you please help me figure it out ?