add or remove validation from input field
I have a checkbox (Have a pet?) and a pet input field with dropdown list ('Dog', 'Cat', 'Other').
If a user ticks the check box, I want to make the pet input field mandatory and the user has to select one from the list.
How can I remove the validation (asp-validation-for="Pet") when the user unticks the checkbox?
In a model
[Required]
[BindProperty]
public int Pet {get; set;}

In a cshtml file
<div style="align-content: center;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="have-pet" />
    <label>Have a pet?</label>
</div>

<div class="form-floating">
    <select asp-for="Pet" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Pets>()" class="form-control" id="pet">
        <option value="@null">Please Select</option>
    </select>
    <label asp-for="Pet"></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="Pet" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>


This is probably the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47965587/14011696
just bind the is required to a check box
