# c# How to Add Custom Validation Based on Boolean

Tags: c#, customvalidator

Here i have a Class Like

```
Public Class Employee
{
       [Required]
        public string FName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Married { get; set; }

        public string WifeName { get; set; }
        public string Wife_dOB { get; set; }

}
```

Here WifeName And Wife_Dob is Required only When Married Is True
Please Help me How can i Resolve this Problem 
Im using Here MVC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally required property using data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354853/conditionally-required-property-using-data-annotations)

Comment: what if the employee is a woman, married to a man? or man to man ?

Comment: What if the employee sues against your enterprise because you are asking informations about private life ?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu No Problem Budy i  will take care

Comment: by the way, required on a bool, makes no sense. bool can only be true or false, it can't be null ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) might be a good choice for your problem. With FluentValidation it would be easy to create an `EmployeeValidator` class to perform as much or as little validation as needed.

*Note: The examples below are written using the standard FluentValidation package since I don't use MVC.  There appears to be nuget packages for several versions of MVC in addition to the standard nuget package and your mileage may vary using those implementations.*

---

Here is a very simple example of how to use FluentValidation:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var emp = new Employee { FName = "John Smith", Married = true };
    var val = new EmployeeValidator();
    val.ValidateAndThrow(emp);
}

public class Employee
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public bool Married { get; set; }
    public string WifeName { get; set; }
    public string Wife_dOB { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(e => e.WifeName).NotEmpty().When(e => e.Married);
        RuleFor(e => e.Wife_dOB).NotEmpty().When(e => e.Married);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
*I forgot to include an example of the output from the validation code above.*

Example output:

> ValidationException: Validation failed: 
>   -- WifeName: 'Wife Name' must not be empty.
>   -- Wife_dOB: 'Wife_d OB' must not be empty.

---

An alternative approach, and in my opinion a better one, would be something like this that requires no validation, at least for the Married property:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string surname, DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {Surname}";
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime dateOfHire)
        : base(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth)
        => DateOfHire = dateOfHire;

    public DateTime DateOfHire { get; }
    public Person Spouse { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarried => Spouse != null;
}
```

With this implementation the `IsMarried` property simply projects whether or not the `Spouse` property is set.  This is purely for convenience but can often be helpful.

---

Some validation that might make sense for these objects could be the following:

```cs
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<IPerson>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.FirstName).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Surname).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.DateOfBirth).SetValidator(new DateOfBirthValidator());
    }
}

public class EmployeeValidator : AbstractValidator<IEmployee>
{
    private static readonly DateTime CompanyInceptionDate
        = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(365.25d * 10d));

    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        // Person rules
        RuleFor(p => p.FirstName).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.Surname).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(p => p.DateOfBirth).SetValidator(new DateOfBirthValidator());

        // Employee rules
        RuleFor(e => e.DateOfHire).SetValidator(
            // Can't be in the future nor older than the company
            new DateRangeValidator(CompanyInceptionDate, DateTime.Today));
    }
}

// This class really isn't necessary
// The built-in InclusiveBetween/ExclusiveBetween validators would work just as well
public class DateRangeValidator : PropertyValidator
{
    protected const double DaysInAYear = 365.25d;

    public DateRangeValidator(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        : base($"{{PropertyName}} out of range. Expected between {from:yyyy-MM-dd} and {to:yyyy-MM-dd}.")
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public DateTime From { get; }
    public DateTime To { get; }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        => context.PropertyValue is DateTime date
            ? date >= From && date <= To
            : false;
}

public class DateOfBirthValidator : DateRangeValidator
{
    private static readonly TimeSpan OneHundredAndFiftyYears
        = TimeSpan.FromDays(DaysInAYear * 150d);

    public DateOfBirthValidator()
        // Can't be in the future nor older than 150 years
        : base(DateTime.Today.Subtract(OneHundredAndFiftyYears), DateTime.Today) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-attributes).

You can see bellow a solution that I used a few time ago:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides conditional validation based on related property value.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
#region Properties

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the other property name that will be used during validation.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The other property name.
/// </value>
public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the display name of the other property.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The display name of the other property.
/// </value>
public string OtherPropertyDisplayName { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the other property value that will be relevant for validation.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The other property value.
/// </value>
public object OtherPropertyValue { get; private set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets a value indicating whether other property's value should match or differ from provided other property's value (default is <c>false</c>).
/// </summary>
/// <value>
///   <c>true</c> if other property's value validation should be inverted; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
/// </value>
/// <remarks>
/// How this works
/// - true: validated property is required when other property doesn't equal provided value
/// - false: validated property is required when other property matches provided value
/// </remarks>
public bool IsInverted { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets a value that indicates whether the attribute requires validation context.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><c>true</c> if the attribute requires validation context; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
public override bool RequiresValidationContext
{
    get { return true; }
}

#endregion

#region Constructor

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiredIfAttribute"/> class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="otherProperty">The other property.</param>
/// <param name="otherPropertyValue">The other property value.</param>
public RequiredIfAttribute(string otherProperty, object otherPropertyValue)
    : base("'{0}' is required because '{1}' has a value {3}'{2}'.")
{
    this.OtherProperty = otherProperty;
    this.OtherPropertyValue = otherPropertyValue;
    this.IsInverted = false;
}

#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Applies formatting to an error message, based on the data field where the error occurred.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The name to include in the formatted message.</param>
/// <returns>
/// An instance of the formatted error message.
/// </returns>
public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        base.ErrorMessageString,
        name,
        this.OtherPropertyDisplayName ?? this.OtherProperty,
        this.OtherPropertyValue,
        this.IsInverted ? "other than " : "of ");
}

/// <summary>
/// Validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value to validate.</param>
/// <param name="validationContext">The context information about the validation operation.</param>
/// <returns>
/// An instance of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult" /> class.
/// </returns>
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (validationContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("validationContext");
    }

    PropertyInfo otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.OtherProperty);
    if (otherProperty == null)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(
            string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Could not find a property named '{0}'.", this.OtherProperty));
    }

    object otherValue = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

    // check if this value is actually required and validate it
    if (!this.IsInverted && object.Equals(otherValue, this.OtherPropertyValue) ||
        this.IsInverted && !object.Equals(otherValue, this.OtherPropertyValue))
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }

        // additional check for strings so they're not empty
        string val = value as string;
        if (val != null && val.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```