# Same class different data annotations

Tags: c#, rest, architecture, data-annotations

Assuming I wan't to use single class to create and update an object in REST API - how I can do this without code duplication?

Create an object (POST) - all fields should be `[Required]`.

Update an object (PATCH) - I want to use same class but fields should not be required as it can be done partially.

I can use below class for POST but can't for PATCH - as only `Name` may be updated (provided along the request) - which is OK.

```
public class Person
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**The only solution I see (that causes code duplication) is:**

```
public class CreatePerson
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class UpdatePerson
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354853/conditionally-required-property-using-data-annotations

Comment: No, this is about fields dependency - not relevant here.

Comment: whit 2 classes in this case it isn't code duplication, this is the right way

Comment: This is simplification - what if in the class there are another nested types with 50 fields in total? I need to duplicate all the content of the class just to remove data annotations. Then in case I need to update/edit any property I need to remember to do it in two classes.

Comment: Why don't you create a dto without annotations? In case of update use it as it is. In case of create use reflection to check that all properties value are different than default.

Comment: Btw why do you use PATCH for update?  Why don't you use PUT?

Comment: PATCH is for partial updates and this is a requirement - I don't want to pass whole object but i.e. add new address item (assuming above example has another Address type filed with another properties.