# Validate fields which are only provided in API JSON body using .NET Data Annotations

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I am working on .NET Core Web API project, I have few data models and implemented data annotations.

While updating user profile, user can enter all fields or only some fields in API JSON body.

How do I check and apply data annotation only if specific field is provided in API JSON.

**Note:** User Id cannot be  updated , it is only for reference.

In below model, I have 4 fields, only User Id is mandatory to be provided in API JSON rest all fields are optional to be entered in JSON while updating.

**Conditions:**

- If any field is provided in API JSON, then it should not be NULL or empty value
- If any field is not provided except `user_id`, it can ignore and do check null annotation for the fields provided.

I know we can validate by removing `Required()` for each column and validate manually.

**Example:**

JSON1

```
{
  "user_id":"XYZ-123"
}
```

**Expected Result:**
Since no optional fields provided, it should Accept and pass validation

**Example:**

JSON2

```
{
  "user_id":"XYZ-123",
  "work_phone":"+91-987654320"
}
```

**Expected Result:**
Since only work phone is provided, it should Accept and pass validation

**Data Model:**

```
public class UserDetails
    {

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The user_id field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("user_id")]
        public string? UserId{ get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The home_phone field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("home_phone")]
        public string? HomePhone { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The work_phone field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("work_phone")]
        public string? WorkPhone { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "The mobile_phone field is required.")]
        [JsonProperty("mobile_phone")]
        public string? MobilePhone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but may be you can use `RegularExpression(@"^[\w\d][\w\d-+]*$")` instead of `Required`. Change the regular expression as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible if you don't get rid of the `Required()` attribute. Required is a data annotation for the view. The view will require it to have a value prior to accepting a form post.

If you want it to be a must in some case, you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354853/conditionally-required-property-using-data-annotations). The `RequiredIf()` attribute used by [DrCopyPaste's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356834/18789859) might help you.