# RequiredIf data annotation attribute not now showing error message

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, data-annotations

I use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27666044/4264597) for `RequiredIf`.

The logic works fine and a `ValidationResult` with the correct error message is being returned.

To display the error message I do the standard:

```
<ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Name)"/>
```

I also add the validation summary for testing purposes:

```
<ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
```

However, the error message is never displayed below the input field. It does however show in the summary. When I change the attribute to the standard `Required`, then the error message is displayed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by adding the `MemberName` as the second parameter when returning the ValidationResult.

This is the complete source code which works with Blazor.

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides conditional validation based on related property value.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the other property name that will be used during validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The other property name.
    /// </value>
    public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the display name of the other property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The display name of the other property.
    /// </value>
    public string OtherPropertyDisplayName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the other property value that will be relevant for validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The other property value.
    /// </value>
    public object OtherPropertyValue { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether other property's value should match or differ from provided other property's value (default is <c>false</c>).
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if other property's value validation should be inverted; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    /// How this works
    /// - true: validated property is required when other property doesn't equal provided value
    /// - false: validated property is required when other property matches provided value
    /// </remarks>
    public bool IsInverted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether the attribute requires validation context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the attribute requires validation context; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public override bool RequiresValidationContext => true;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequiredIfAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="otherProperty">The other property.</param>
    /// <param name="otherPropertyValue">The other property value.</param>
    public RequiredIfAttribute(string otherProperty, object otherPropertyValue)
        : base("'{0}' is required because '{1}' has a value {3}'{2}'.")
    {
        this.OtherProperty = otherProperty;
        this.OtherPropertyValue = otherPropertyValue;
        this.IsInverted = false;
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies formatting to an error message, based on the data field where the error occurred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name to include in the formatted message.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the formatted error message.
    /// </returns>
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            base.ErrorMessageString,
            name,
            this.OtherPropertyDisplayName ?? this.OtherProperty,
            this.OtherPropertyValue,
            this.IsInverted ? "other than " : "of ");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to validate.</param>
    /// <param name="validationContext">The context information about the validation operation.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult" /> class.
    /// </returns>
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(validationContext));
        }

        var otherProperty = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.OtherProperty);
        if (otherProperty == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(
                string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Could not find a property named '{0}'.", this.OtherProperty));
        }

        var otherValue = otherProperty.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        //Check if this value is actually required and validate it
        if (!this.IsInverted && object.Equals(otherValue, this.OtherPropertyValue) ||
            this.IsInverted && !object.Equals(otherValue, this.OtherPropertyValue))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), 
                    new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }

            //Additional check for strings so they're not empty
            var val = value as string;
            if (val != null && val.Trim().Length == 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), 
                    new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```