# Exception to the rule - how to override a required attribute on one item when using data annotations with a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a list of objects for my ASP.NET MVC model `List<NameAddressModel>`. In this abbreviated example, we're only looking at the first name. The model has the `[Required]` attribute, which will normally apply to all of the items, but I only need two of three `InputFirstName`s filled out. What is the way to make the third item not required? Or do I have to do something different than using the `[Required]` attribute this way?

My model class:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string? InputFirstName { get; set; }
```

The view:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    <div> 
        <label asp-for="InputFirstName[i]"></label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for=InputFirstName[i]  />
    </div>
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is what you are after:
[Conditionally required property using data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354853/conditionally-required-property-using-data-annotations)

Comment: @JayV - yes, that is. I couldn't figure out how to ask the right question. Thanks!