# Configure Conditional Viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a viewmodel with the following two fields:

```
public bool IsMobile {get; set;}
public bool? AcceptSms {get; set;}
```

If IsMobile is set to true, I need to require a value for AcceptSms, not null. 
I cant figure out the structure to use the get or set function to require value.

Something like below is what I think I need ...

```
public bool? AcceptSms 
{ get 
    { if(IsMobile == true)
       {return ...}
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not an option to default AcceptSms to false and make it not nullable? But have a look at conditional validation attributes to help with the front end :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642328/how-to-put-conditional-required-attribute-into-class-property-to-work-with-web-a
and/or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898181/c-sharp-custom-attribute-required-if

Comment: If you want both server side and client side validation, [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) have some useful conditional validation attributes including `[RequiredIfTrue]` which should suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for.  If you'll add as answer, I'll accept.