# Jquery If radio button is clicked, require email field

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my problem.
I have a razor generated form that has multiple fields but I want email to only be required if the System Admin radio button is clicked.  It is defaulted to system user.

```
<div class="">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)</div>
     <div class="">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control required", placeholder = "Email" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
     </div>
```

I even tried removing the "required" after form control and taking out the validation.

I have 2 radio buttons that are generated by razor that have the same
   name but different values.

```
<div class="inline-editor create-user-roles">
    <input id="UserRole" name="UserRole" type="radio" value="System Administrator">
    <input id="UserRole" name="UserRole" type="radio" value="System User">
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery function that I am trying to use.

```
$('input[name="UserRole"]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('input[name="UserRole"]:checked').val() == "System Administrator") {
        $('#Email').rules('add', {
            required: true, messages: { required: "This field is required" }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#Email').rules('add', {
            required: false
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you need to update your js like this `if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'System Administrator')` and replace `click` with `change`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick.  It's still letting me submit the form without an email @Sushil

Comment: first of all you have multiple elements with the same id. that needs to go. then instead of using `$('#UserRole').click` try using `$('input[name="UserRole"]').on('change', function())`

Comment: Yeah, it's not valid to have multiple elements with the same `id`. The `id` attributes need to be unique, even if the `name` attributes are the same.

Comment: I attempted another js function that i just added  but that didn't seem to fix the problem either.

Comment: I simplified my js and checked it in the console.  I think maybe its a problem with adding the rules?

Comment: you dont need to write this again `$('input[name="UserRole"]:checked')`. instead just use `if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'System Administrator')`

Comment: You could use a [RequiredIf attribute][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out.  I found a simpler way of doing it that solved all my problems.  Here is is!

```
$('input[name="UserRole"]').on('change', function () {
    if ($('input[name="UserRole"]:checked').val() == "System Administrator")     {
        $("#Email").removeClass('form-control').addClass('form-control required');
    }
    else {
        $("#Email").removeClass('form-control required').addClass('form-control');
        $("span[for^='Email']").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not really solve anything since you need to repeat the logic again in the server. Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf("UserRole", "System Administrator")]` or similar attribute so you get both client and server side validation out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using [jQueryValidation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) [*from the syntax*]. Changing your code to the following should do the trick:

```
$('input[name="UserRole"]').on('change', function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == "System Administrator") {  // `this` refers to the current element that has raised the event, i.e. shorter for `input[name="UserRole"]` in this case
   $('#Email').rules('add', {
        required: true, messages: { required: "This field is required" }
       });
   }
   else {
       $('#Email').rules('remove');  // Take note of this part
   }
});
```

*Notice that you need to* **remove** *the rule.* Specifying `false` on a particular rule will not have any effect on removing it.

**Update:** Using the `.rules()` method on form elements requires that you have already invoked the `.validate()` method [*with an empty object*] on the form.

That is, add the following line before the above block of code:

```
$('#yourFormId').validate({});

//rest of your code where you can add your validation rules with `.rule()`.
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but that still does not work.  I am still able to submit a form without an email with the system admin button checked.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this as well but to no avail.  I posted an answer that I got to work.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Will your method prevent the form from being submitted as I see you're neither returning `false` nor doing `e.preventDefault()` on the submit handler.