# RequiredIf conditional attribute in .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-3.0, model-validation, expressiveannotations

How to achieve RequiredIf conditional operation in .NET Core for Model based validation.

In ASP.NET MVC, had used with ExpressiveAnnotation package but its not working for .NET Core.

Answer (score 7):

*UoN.ExpressiveAnnotations.NetCore* is the package used for .NET Core applications same functionality as *ExpressiveAnnotation* package for MVC

Reference URL: https://github.com/uon-nuget/UoN.ExpressiveAnnotations.NetCore

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `RequiredAttribute` to check the property value and according to that   manually check IsNullOrWhiteSpace of current property .

You can find the code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175740/5751404) . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56462845/5751404) is another code sample using custom ValidationAttribute .