# Enabling required attribute validation only after a field clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, .net-core-3.1

If I have the following viemodel properties:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email field is required.")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a valid email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The first name field is required.")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z\\-]+$", ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid name")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The last name field is required.")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z\\-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid name")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Then how do I only enable required fields on front-end ONLY after the fields are clicked on and clicked away from?

Currently the error messages are presented to the viewer straight away:

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBdF8.png)

The front-end razor page is using blazorise validation, which only validates if all fields have been filled:

```
<Form method="post">
<Validations Mode="ValidationMode.Auto" Model="@ExampleViewModel" ValidatedAll="IsInvalid">
<Validation>
    <Blazorise.Field>
        <Blazorise.FieldLabel Class="is-bold">Email address</Blazorise.FieldLabel>
        <Blazorise.TextEdit Placeholder="Enter email" @bind-Text="@ContactDetails.Email" MaxLength=40>
            <Feedback>
                <ValidationError />
            </Feedback>
        </Blazorise.TextEdit>
    </Blazorise.Field>
</Validation>
<Row>
    <Blazorise.Title Size="10">Your Details</Blazorise.Title>
</Row>
<Validation>
    <Blazorise.Field>
        <Blazorise.FieldLabel Class="is-bold">First name</Blazorise.FieldLabel>
        <Blazorise.TextEdit Placeholder="John" @bind-Text="@ContactDetails.Forename" MaxLength=40>
            <Feedback>
                <ValidationError/>
            </Feedback>
        </Blazorise.TextEdit>
    </Blazorise.Field>
</Validation>
<Validation>
    <Blazorise.Field>
        <Blazorise.FieldLabel Class="is-bold">Last name</Blazorise.FieldLabel>
        <Blazorise.TextEdit Placeholder="Doe" @bind-Text="@ContactDetails.Surname" MaxLength=40>
            <Feedback>
                <ValidationError />
            </Feedback>
        </Blazorise.TextEdit>
    </Blazorise.Field>
</Validation>
```

Comment: you can remove the attribute from class and do validation in the click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is going to be available in the next version, v0.9.1.

Comment: The next version of what exactly?

Comment: The next version of Blazorise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help :
[RequiredIf Conditional Validation Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390902/requiredif-conditional-validation-attribute)

If you want to work with data annotation you can create a property boolean in your view model that indicates if you should check the required or not.

```
public bool HasUserClicked { get; set; }

[RequiredIf(nameof("HasUserClicked",true)
public string MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

When the user click you switch that boolean.

**Edit**
Not sure it will work with Blazor by the way...
And if you want to have more conditional validation you should maybe consider [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/).

Comment: `RequiredIf` is not available in .net core 3.1, I have tried extending `RequiredAttribute` class  as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321148/conditional-validation-in-mvc-net-core-requiredif/59175740#59175740) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but exactly the opposite, and it turns out that, you can toggle immediate validation off by excluding `<DataAnnotationsVAlidator/>` from your `EditForm`

For example say I had a class like this:

```cs
public class Apple {
  [Required]
  public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

This would cause the form to be validated, even if the user didn't type anything into `Color`.

```cs
 <EditForm OnValidSubmit="OnValidDevSubmit" EditContext="EditContext">
   <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
   <MudTextField T="string" Label="Color" Required="true" @bind-Value="apple.Color"/>
   <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit">Submit</MudButton>
</EditForm>
```

On the otherhand, this would cause the form to be validated only if the user had clicked on `Color` and then clicked away.

```cs
 <EditForm OnValidSubmit="OnValidDevSubmit" EditContext="EditContext">
   <MudTextField T="string" Label="Color" Required="true" @bind-Value="apple.Color"/>
   <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit">Submit</MudButton>
</EditForm>
```