# Disabling Client Side Validation For Disabled Input Controls In ASP.NET MVC using MicrosoftMVCJqueryValidation.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation

I am using MicrosoftMVCJqueryValidation.js and want to
Disable Client Side Validation For Disabled Input Controls.

Or is there any way to enable/disable client side validation using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the unobtrusive validation metadata when a form element is disabled and add it again if it is enabled. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389652/disable-required-validation-by-javascript) on stackoverflow would help.

Comment: How can i do this using client side javascript?